# What is an efficient way to search a huge file for many strings of characters?

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I'm trying to get back into Perl and having a bugger of time with my code.  I have a large source .DAT file (2GB).  I have another .TXT file that contains the strings (almost 2000 of them) I am wanting to search for in that .DAT file.  I throw the values from that .TXT file into an array.

I want to efficiently do a search for each of those strings in the array, and output the matches.  Can anyone help straighten me out?  Thanks in advance!

```
my $source = "/KEYS.txt";
my $data= "/claims.dat";
my @array;
my $arraySize = scalar (@DESYarray);

open (DAT, $data) or die "Cannot open file!";
open (LOG, ">>/output.log");

open (TXT,$source);
while (my $searchValues = <TXT>) {
    push (@array, $searchValues);
}
close (TXT);


while (my $line = <DAT>) {      
for (my $x = 0; $x <= $arraySize; $x++) {
    if (my $line =~ /$array[$x]/) {
        print LOG $line;
    }
}
}

close (DAT);
close (LOG);
```

Comment: For this particular problem, you can probably use `grep` (the linux/unix version, not perl). E.g. `grep -f /KEYS.txt /claims.dat`.

Comment: Are the strings in KEYS.txt fixed or are they regular expressions? If they are fixed, you get a huge speed win with `grep -F -f KEYS.txt claims.dat`; the Perl code would use the [`index`](http://p3rl.org/index) function instead of the match operator.

Comment: In KEYS.txt, they are actually 9 digits long. So 102361550 and 481543095 etc

Comment: As other posters said, `grep` is probably right for this job. Assuming you want to use Perl for academic reasons, you can get an easy speed boost by changing the reading of the TXT file to `push @array, qr/$searchValues/;`. That will precompile the regex so you don't have to do it again while going over the DAT file.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  I'll check out your comments and suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring `my $line` in your inner loop, which means it will be equal to:

```
if (undef =~ /$array[$x]/) {
```

Which of course will always fail. If you had used `use warnings`, you would have gotten the error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ...
```

Which makes me suspect you are not using warnings, which is a **very** bad idea.

Also, keep in mind that when you read values into `@array`, you will get a newline at the end, so you are searching your DAT file for strings that end with `\n`, which may not be what you want. E.g. if you have `foo\n`, it will not match `foo bar baz`.

The solution to that is to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your data:

```
chomp(my @array = <TXT>);
```

Yes, you can chomp an array, and you can assign an entire file to an array this way.

You can and should improve your script a little. It is quite unnecessary to loop using array indexes, unless you in fact need to use the indexes for something.

```
use strict;
use warnings;    # ALWAYS use these!
use autodie;     # handles the open statements for convenience

my $source = "/KEYS.txt";
my $data= "/claims.dat";

open $txt, '<', $source;
chomp(my @array = <$txt>);
close $txt;

open my $dat, '<', $data;   # use three argument open and lexical file handle
open my $log, '>>', "/output.log";

while (<$dat>) {            # using $_ for convenience
    for my $word (@array) {
        if (/\Q$word/i) {   # adding /i modifier to match case insensitively
            print $log $line;   # also adding \Q to match literal strings
    }
}
```

Using `\Q` might be very important, depending on what your KEYS.txt file contains. Meta characters for regexes may cause subtle mismatches, if you are expecting them to match literally. E.g. if you have a word such as `foo?`, the regex `/foo?/` will match `foo`, but it will also match `for`.

Also, you may wish to decide whether to allow partial matches. E.g. `/foo/` will also match `football`. To overcome that, one way is to use the word boundary escape character:

```
/\b\Q$word\E\b/i
```

You will need to place them outside the `\Q .. \E` sequence, or they will be interpreted literally.

**ETA:** As tchrist points out and Borodin suggests, building a regex with all the words will save you getting duplicate lines. E.g. if you have the words `"foo"`, `"bar"` and `"baz"`, and the line `foo bar baz` you would get this line printed three times, once for each matching word.

This may be fixed afterwards, by deduping your data in some suitable way. Only you know your data and whether this is a problem or not. I would hesitate to compile such a long regex, for performance reasons, but you can try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: You should precompile your regexes. Also, why print a line for each match? Just print a line for any match.  Which leads to a `...|...|...|...` solution, which will be optimized into a trie data structure.

Comment: @tchrist Because I am not sure building a 2000 word regex is optimal. Perhaps perl can optimize it in such a way that it is a good idea.

Comment: @tchrist By precompile, I assume you mean something like `@array = map qr/\Q$_/i, @array`? Would that improve performance?

Comment: If you write it as a loop, then it is O(N) for N equal alternatives. If you write it as `…|…|…|…`, then it is O(1) for N equal alternatives.  Run under `perl -Mre=debug` to see the Aho–Corasick trie optimization in action.

Answer (score 1):

You should always start your program with `use strict` and `use warnings`, especially if you are asking for help with your code. They are an enormous help with debugging and will often find simple mistakes that are otherwise easily overlooked.

How long are the strings in *KEYS.txt*? It may be feasible to build a regex from them using `join '|', @array`. By the way, the code you have written is equivalent to `@array = <TXT>`, and don't forget to chomp the contents!

I suggest something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $source = "/KEYS.txt";
my $data= "/claims.dat";

open my $dat, '<', $data or die "Cannot open data file: $!";
open my $log, '>>', '/output.log' or die "Cannot open output file: $!";

open my $txt, '<', $source or die "Cannot open keys file: $!";
my @keys = <$txt>;
chomp @keys;
close $txt;

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @keys;
$regex = qr/$regex/i;

while (my $line = <$dat>) {
  next unless $line =~ $regex;
  print $log $line;
}

close $log or die "Unable to close log file: $!";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Regexp::Assemble in the past to take a list of tokens, create a optimized regexp and use it filter large amounts of text.  Once we moved from a | delimited regexp to Regexp::Assemble we saw a great performance boost.

[Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aAssemble)

Comment: This happens automatically now. http://p3rl.org/perl5100delta#Trie-optimisation-of-literal-string-alternations